# How can i replace space with _ (underscore) in a string?

Tags: string, replace, str-replace

Suppose initial string is

```
String result= "Welcome To All" for that i need updated result as
String result="Welcome_To_All"  string value is dynamic,how can i do that,thank for help?
```

Comment: what language are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for

```
    string oldstr = "Hello World";
    string s = oldstr.Replace(" ", "_");
    (s == "Hello_World");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you're using javascript and you're ok with using regular expressions.

```
result = result.replace(/ /g, "_");
```